# How to Pass Ampersands As Part of a Parameter Value with Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm making a `GET` request from one webservice to another, and I need to pass a parameter that has an ampersand in its value.  E.g. `GET http://sandwich.com?flavor=[value]` where `[value]` should be PB&J.  However, performing this with Spring's `RestTemplate` seems to be impossible.

When I make this call through `cURL`, I simply replace the ampersand with `%26`, i.e. `flavor=PB%26J`.

However, when I pass the URL to Spring's `RestTemplate.exchange(String, HttpMethod, HttpEntity<?>, Class<T>)`, it seems to escape characters selectively.  That is, if I pass in `flavor=PB%26J`, it escapes the percent symbol, resulting in `flavor=PB%2526J`.  However, if I pass in `flavor=PB&J`, it leaves the ampersand alone, resulting in `flavor=PB&J`, which is treated as two parameters.

I've tracked this down to where `RestTemplate` calls `UriTemplateHandler.expand(String, Object...)`, but I'm not sure what I can do from here, as none of the input values I start with lead to the desired `PB%26J`.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the url string with the help of the `UriComponentsBuilder`. The `encode()` method should help you encode the url properly.

```
String url = UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromUriString("http://sandwich.com")
        .queryParam("flavor", "PB&J")
        .encode() // this should help with encoding the url properly
        .build().toString(); // Gives http://sandwich.com?flavor=PB%26J
RestTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod, HttpEntity<?>, Class<T>)
```

Or better yet, just pass the `URI` object instead

```
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromUriString("http://sandwich.com")
        .queryParam("flavor", "PB&J")
        .encode() // this should help with encoding the url properly
        .build();
RestTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod, HttpEntity<?>, Class<T>)
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case this should work:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public List<Entity> list(@PathParam("flavor") String[] values) throws Exception {
```